# Python: To combine lines of a text file and skip certain records

Tags: python

I have an input file like below (please note that there may/may not be blank lines in the file

11111*Author Name

22222*Date

11111 01 Var-1

11111    02 Var-2

11111    02 Var-3

Rules to be used:

- If asterisk(*) is present at position # 6 of a record then skip the record.
- First 6 bytes are sequence number which can be spaces as well. However, the first six bytes whether space or number can be ignored.
- Only combine the records where asterisk is not present at position # 6.
- Only consider data starting from position 7 in the input file up to positon 72.
- Add comma as shown below

Expected Output
01,Var-1,02,Var-2,02,Var-3

Below is the code that I was trying to print the record. However, I was not able to get comma(,) after each text. Some were prefixed with spaces. Can someone please help?

```
with open("D:/Desktop/Files/Myfile.txt","r") as file_in:
    for lines in file_in:
        if "*" not in lines:
            lines_new = " ".join(lines.split())
            lines_fin = lines_new.replace(' ',',')
            print(lines_fin,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to print them one after another (they will still be on separate lines)

```
with open("D:/Desktop/Files/Myfile.txt","r") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        if line == "\n": # skip empty lines
            continue 
        if line[5] == "*": #skip if asterix at 6th position
            continue
        line = line.strip() # remove trailing and starting whitespace
        line = line.replace(' ', ',') # replace remaining spaces with commas
        print(line, ',')
```

If you just want them all combined then a better way to do it would be:

```
with open("D:/Desktop/Files/Myfile.txt","r") as f:
    all_lines = f.readlines()

all_lines = [line.strip().replace(" ",",") for line in all_lines if line != "\n" and line[5] != "*"]
all_lines = ",".join(all_lines)
```

I havent tested this so may have typos!

Comment: I just tested the 2nd method: it works, after fixing an error and a typo: if line doesn't work, replace with if line != "\n", and the typo is a missing " after *.

Comment: Sorry, hit Enter too fast :) ; I'm not the OP, so I'll only upvote your answer :) . While you're at it, fix the "if not line" in your 1st version too.

Comment: No worries - have fixed both. Hadn't thoroughly tested as writing on my phone! Thanks for pointing out! Thanks in advance for the upvote - new to this so keen to get better rep!

Comment: Both versions work now.

Comment: Thank you!!
This (second solution) was close to what I needed. While testing I realized that my file had more than one space between two strings so I replaced multiple spaces between strings in a line with one space and then replaced that space with comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Python's pathlib as it has some useful capabilities for handling paths and reading text files.

To join items together it is useful to put the items you want to join in a Python list and then use the `join` method on the list.

I have also changed the logic of how you are splitting the data. When a line is kept, the line is always the first 6 characters removed so these can be sliced off. If you do that first it makes the split on whitespace cleaner as you get the two items you are seeking.

There seemed to be a requirement to truncate the data if it was longer than 72 characters so I limited the line of data to 72 characters.

This is what my test code looked like:

```py
from pathlib import Path

data_file = Path("D:/Desktop/Files/Myfile.txt")
field_size = 72


def combine_file_contents(filename):
    combined_data = []
    for line in filename.read_text().splitlines():
        if line and line[5] != "*":
            combined_data.extend(line[6:field_size].split())
    return ','.join(combined_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    expected_output = "01,Var-1,02,Var-2,02,Var-3"
    output_data = combine_file_contents(data_file)
    print("New Output:     ", output_data)
    print("Expected Output:", expected_output)
    assert output_data == expected_output
```

This gave the following output when I ran with the test data from the question:

```
New Output:      01,Var-1,02,Var-2,02,Var-3
Expected Output: 01,Var-1,02,Var-2,02,Var-3
```

Comment: Thank you!! The solution that you provided worked for the scenario that I was trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex solution would be elegant
You would need to handle the limit of 72 for the length of data, but that should not be a problem.

```
import re

pattern = r'[\s\d]{6}(.+)'
out = []
with open('combinestrings.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        result = re.findall(pattern, line)
        if result:
            out.append(','.join(result[0].split(' ')))
    print(','.join(out))
```

output:

```
01,Var-1,02,Var-2,02,Var-3
```